# Makefile/double compilation

Tags: c++, precompiled-headers

Recently I noticed (after others have extended the project) that the compile time significantly increased. I was suggested to make use of c++ precompiled headers. The "include" parts are moved to a separate file "precompiled.h"

```
#include <iostream>

#include <stxxl/vector>
#include <stxxl/priority_queue>
#include <stxxl/sort>
#include <stxxl/scan>
#include <stxxl/stream>

#include <string> 
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>  
#include <vector>   
#include <limits.h>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <fstream>              
#include <cairo.h>
#include <cairo-pdf.h>
#include "myFile1.cpp"
#include "myFile2.cpp"
```

and the header file specific makefile has the following content:

```
STXXL_ROOT      ?= /home/mirza/stxxl-1.2.1
STXXL_CONFIG    ?= stxxl.mk
include $(STXXL_ROOT)/$(STXXL_CONFIG)

# use the variables from stxxl.mk

CXX              = $(STXXL_CXX)
CPPFLAGS        += $(STXXL_CPPFLAGS)

# add your own optimization, warning, debug, ... flags
# (these are *not* set in stxxl.mk)
CPPFLAGS        += $(shell pkg-config --cflags cairo)
STXXL_LDLIBS    += $(shell pkg-config --libs cairo)

CPPFLAGS        += -O3 -Wall -g -c -DFOO=BAR

# build your application
# (my_example.o is generated from my_example.cpp automatically)

precompiled.o: precompiled.h
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) precompiled.h -o $@ $(STXXL_LDLIBS)
```

Of course, the first line in the main .cpp file is "include "precompiled.h"". However, after executing main file specific make file, I get the reports and warnings that I got when compiling "precompiled.h" file (warnings and reports related to myFile1.cpp myFile1.cpp). I guess the compilation process is repeated.
I've read that the precompiled headers are associated with .gch files, which I did not manage to generate.
Any help on this is highly appreciated. Thanks

I guess it would be helpful to include the content of the makefile specific for the main .cpp file. Perhaps by changing this file I could "tell the compiler" that the load was done once.

```
STXXL_ROOT      ?= /home/mirza/stxxl-1.2.1
STXXL_CONFIG    ?= stxxl.mk
include $(STXXL_ROOT)/$(STXXL_CONFIG)

# use the variables from stxxl.mk

CXX              = $(STXXL_CXX)
CPPFLAGS        += $(STXXL_CPPFLAGS)

# add your own optimization, warning, debug, ... flags
# (these are *not* set in stxxl.mk)

CPPFLAGS        += $(shell pkg-config --cflags cairo)
STXXL_LDLIBS    += $(shell pkg-config --libs cairo)


CPPFLAGS        += -O3 -Wall -g -DFOO=BAR

# build your application
# (my_example.o is generated from my_example.cpp automatically)
fileA.bin: fileA.o
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) fileA.o -o $@ $(STXXL_LDLIBS)
```

Comment: Look at gcc documentation (for instance http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.2/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html#Precompiled-Headers, but use the documentation corresponding to the gcc you are using), it describes how to generate pre-compiled headers (we don't do it, experiments showed it unprofitable on our code base).

Comment: And BTW, including .cpp files is probably a mistake.

Comment: @user506901: `#include "xxx.cpp"` is frightening.

Comment: Thanks. I renamed the included .cpp files to .h files. But, again, after invoking the main .cpp file specific makefile, I get the same reports and warnings? Should this be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `precompiled.o: precompiled.h` rule to `precompiled.h.gch: precompiled.h` so GCC knows it's the precompiled header